# Unable to start Angular 2 project

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I don't know what happened, but for some reason all of a suddent I can't start my Angular 2 project anymore and I can't figure out why based on the error.....

```
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(21,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(85,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'name' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(145,5): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '[Symbol.unscopables]' must be of type '{ copyWithin: boolean; entries: boolean; fill: boolean; find: boolean; findIndex: boolean; keys: ...', but here has type 'any'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(262,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'flags' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(276,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'EPSILON' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(311,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'MAX_SAFE_INTEGER' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(318,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'MIN_SAFE_INTEGER' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(457,5): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '[Symbol.toStringTag]' must be of type '"Symbol"', but here has type 'string'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(457,5): error TS2687: All declarations of '[Symbol.toStringTag]' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(464,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(492,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'hasInstance' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(498,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'isConcatSpreadable' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(504,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'iterator' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(510,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'match' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(516,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'replace' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(522,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'search' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(528,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'species' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(534,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'split' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(540,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'toPrimitive' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(546,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'toStringTag' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(552,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'unscopables' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(609,5): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '[Symbol.toStringTag]' must be of type '"Math"', but here has type 'string'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(609,5): error TS2687: All declarations of '[Symbol.toStringTag]' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(613,5): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '[Symbol.toStringTag]' must be of type '"JSON"', but here has type 'string'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(613,5): error TS2687: All declarations of '[Symbol.toStringTag]' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(628,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'size' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(634,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(645,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'size' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(651,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(666,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(680,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(692,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'value' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(804,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(4133,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Error\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! otb-app@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" `
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the otb-app@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" '.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the otb-app package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs otb-app
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls otb-app
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     Z:\Google Drive\Programming\Apps\SubCon - Web App\npm-debug.log
```

I've tried and I can't decipher it. I don't know what I did in which file to cause it to completely shut down.... I can provide more info, but I really don't have a clue what would be helpful

Comment: Its incomplete information. I d suggest you to delete node_modules folder manually and  do npm install again.

Comment: OMG it's fixed!!! I re-installed it before posting my question, but it didn't do anything because I didn't erase the folder first. After deleting and re-installing it's working perfectly!

Thank you so much! Make it an answer so I can accept that as the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, something may go wrong with `npm install` due to network trouble or something. So if you keep on facing the problem repeatedly, it's better to erase `node_modules folder` and re-run `npm install` command.